# Discord bot can't show emote "sometimes"

Tags: node.js, discord

As a french Gwent player, I built a discord bot (using node.js and discord.js) to show the infos of a card when you name it. It uses some custom emotes to show some part of it.

[image]

It worked well for a few weeks, but recently some cards don't show the emotes when called.

[image]

I have no clue about what could be wrong. The emotes work if you use it yourself on the channel. Some cards show the emotes, others don't, even if they use the same emotes. And it's always all emotes or none for each card.

I checked different cards from my database : with or without emotes, I can't get any specific element which can explain why some cards can have emotes and why some cannot.

Is there something to know here that can explain this situation ?

Answer (score 7):

Although this a late answer and you may have found an answer to the question but I'm going to post an answer anyways for others.

First in the chat you have to type:

```
\:custom_emote_here:
```

so in your case, you want it to show

[image]

and the name of it was **:number5:**, you would type *:number5:*.

You would get something like this:
[image] (of course, it would say :number5: and the start and the numbers would be different)

You can copy and paste that into your code.
For example:

`message.channel.send("<:super_magical:366208548914331659>")`

would show this:

[image]

Hope this helps!

[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)[discord](/questions/tagged/discord)[discord.js](/questions/tagged/discord.js)[emote](/questions/tagged/emote)

Comment: not working that way anymore, i think, I did this way and when I test it sends the emote name only without number and <> and don't converts to img.

Answer (score 1):

The developers of Discord have recently changed the way bots work with regards to custom emoji.

Before May 16th, bots could use any custom emoji from any server provided they are used inside rich embeds, as shown in your screenshot.

After that date, bots can use custom emoji from shared servers, but do not have to limit it to rich embeds only.

If you have the bot join all the servers that these custom emoji are being hosted on then it will be able to start using the emotes again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that's not it : as I said, for some cards the emote is here, for some others it's not, event if it's the SAME emote. I think something makes the emotes not working in some embed messages, but I don't get it. And btw, the bot is on the server these custom emotes are ;)

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question was asked quite a whiles ago but I thought I'd offer a solution I found after recently running into this issue myself for anyone else also facing this problem.

Normally, when you send an emoji in a message or embed via the <:name:id> format, Discord will convert it to a custom emoji. However, there are two cases where it represents all custom emojis in a message in the :name: format as shown in your example.

1. If one of the custom emojis you are trying to send are no longer active in the server (i.e. you have removed it from the server).
2. If you are trying to send an animated emoji via the <:name:id> format.

If either of the above two conditions are met, it seems like Discord defaults to converting all emojis in the message to :name: rather than the actual custom emoji.

I fixed it for myself by making sure that all of the emojis currently exist in the server emoji list before sending them. For animated emoji, you should send it via the <:a:name:id> format instead.