# Discord bot doesn't show emotes from other servers in embeds

Tags: vb.net, discord.net

I'm working on a Discord bot using [Discord.Net 2.2.0](https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net) and written in VB.NET. One of the (*overly-ambitious?*) many features of my bot will be posting player data from the mobile game, *Star Wars: Galaxy of Heroes* into an embed. This includes certain character ability information in which I wish to include some emotes to make it a bit more aesthetically pleasing. Initially, I had uploaded the emotes to a server I was testing in and everything worked great:

[image: Embed with emotes loaded from only the client/target server]

However, I realized that, if my bot makes it out into the wild, I can't really be installing these emotes on every server out there. I'm still in the beginning stages of this project, and I foresee the need for several "custom" emotes for some of the embeds I'll be using. So, I decided to create a new Discord server (*henceforth referred to as the bot's "home" server*) in which to load these emotes for use in the "client" or "target" server.

Unfortunately, when I try to include emotes from the bot's home server in the embed, all I get are the emote names and no images:

[image: Embed with emotes loaded from only the home server]

After fighting with it a bit, I tried including emotes from both servers in the same embed and I get "mixed" results. Those emotes that I include which are loaded in the client/target server show up correctly, but those that are from the bot's home server only display the emote name:

[image: Embed with emotes loaded from both home and client/target server]

The method is pretty long, so here's a *very* simplified example of the code I'm using to create the embeds:

```vb
Dim BotHomeServer As Discord.WebSocket.SocketGuild = BotClient.GetGuild(Convert.ToUInt64(HOME_SERVER_ID))
Dim TargetServer As Discord.WebSocket.SocketGuild = BotClient.GetGuild(Convert.ToUInt64(TARGET_SERVER_ID))
Dim PostingChannel As Discord.WebSocket.SocketTextChannel = TargetServer.GetTextChannel(Convert.ToUInt64(POST_CHANNEL_ID))
Dim HomeEmote As Discord.Emote = Await BotHomeServer.GetEmoteAsync(EMOTE_ID_FROM_HOME_SERVER)
Dim TargetEmote As Discord.Emote = Await TargetServer.GetEmoteAsync(EMOTE_ID_FROM_TARGET_SERVER)
Dim PostBuilder As New Discord.EmbedBuilder

  '... other fields and properties of the embed
PostBuilder.AddField("Home Server Test", "Some Text Here <:" & HomeEmote.Name & ":" & HomeEmote.Id & ">", False)
PostBuilder.AddField("Target Server Test", "Some Text Here <:" & TargetEmote.Name & ":" & TargetEmote.Id & ">", False)
  '... other fields and properties of the embed

Await PostingChannel.SendMessageAsync("This is a test", False, PostBuilder.Build)
```

I've also tried using the `.ToString()` method for adding the emotes to the embed instead of "manually" building them with the `Name` and `Id` properties, but I get the exact same results. I retrieved the emote ID's by typing `\:emotename:` in the home (and client/target) server. The emote names (i.e., `:gohomega:`) are correct, so I know that it's correctly finding the emote in the bot's home server. It's just not displaying them unless they're loaded in the client/target server.

I found a *similar* issue addressed in the question, [Discord bot can't show emote “sometimes”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45263865/discord-bot-cant-show-emote-sometimes). Although the issue reported there is definitely different, the end result - the emote names showing up instead of the actual image - is the same behavior I'm trying to troubleshoot. The fact that the issue in that question is sporadic (whereas my issue is consistent) and that the bot there is written in a different language (Node.js instead of a .NET language) and using different libraries (I assume) has me wondering if the issue may be on Discord's end rather than anything to do with my code.

I've triple- and quadruple-checked that the bot (and the role group it's in) have permission to use external emojis on the client/target server:

[image: Target server permission settings for bot role]

Initially, I had forgotten this bit and it didn't have the appropriate permissions. However, even after granting the necessary permissions, I still get the same results.

At this point, I'm not above admitting that I may just be overlooking/missing something, or simply being dense about what I'm looking at, but I'm wondering if anyone else has encountered (and hopefully resolved) this particular issue with a bot using emotes from a different server.

---

### EDIT

Just to make certain, I stepped through the code in my IDE and checked the properties of one of the emotes at the time it's supposedly being added to the embed:

[image: Emote object definition at runtime]

The emote's `Id` and `Url` properties appear to be correct, but I also went ahead and "validated" the `Url` property with my browser and verified that it does show the correct image for the emote.

Per the comments, the bot *is* a member of both servers:

[image: Membership listings for each server]

I'm grasping at straws here, but perhaps it has something to do with the fact that the "home" server is so new (I just created it last night)? I mean, Discord's documentation says this should work, and the Discord.Net documentation basically says the same thing. According to the comments, it works for other people and my code *looks* "right", so it's really leading me to believe the entire issue is something on Discord's end.

I've also asked this question in both the **[Discord API](https://discord.gg/discord-api)** server (`#dotnet_discord-net`) and the **[Discord Bots](https://discord.gg/0cDvIgU2voWn4BaD)** server (`#development`), so feel free to join me in one of those servers for an "extended conversation", if needed.

Comment: And the bot is in the home server right?

Comment: Yes, the bot is a member of the home server. Of course, it's currently offline, but it does show up in the member list on the right in both servers. I also have a bit of code implemented ahead of my testing code that's supposedly waiting for the bot to be connected before even attempting to post anything.

Comment: @Anu6is - I just had a thought... The code for my bot is currently only instantiating *one* `DiscordSocketClient` object, even though it's connecting to two different servers. I *probably* need to instantiate two separate `DiscordSocketClient` objects (one for each server connection), don't I?

Comment: No, there should only be one instance of the client. One client, multiple guilds

Comment: I just tested this and it works just fine for me, using either Emote.Parse or adding the string directly.

Comment: Unrelated, don't you use `Imports`? Having to repeat things like `Discord.WebSocket.SocketGuild` over and over is a bit monotonous and muddles up the code. Also using `CULng` instead of `Convert.ToUInt64`

Comment: Okay, so the code should basically be "okay", it's just something *else* that's causing a problem with parsing the emote. *And, yes. I do use `Imports` quite a bit, but for the sake of clarity and reproducibility when posting on a site like this, I tend to fully qualify things as much as possible.*

Comment: Noted, yeah the code should be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I finally found the cause of the issue, and I feel like a moron. I spent all my time looking at the bot's permissions and the group permissions at the server level, but I didn't even *think* about the actual channel permissions. The `Use External Emoji` permission for bot's group role in the channel was set to inherit:

[image: Use External Emoji permission setting]

I set it to allow and, *voilà*, the emotes came through just fine. I checked the permissions for the category that the text channel is in and found that the bot/group roles weren't even listed. I guess I had mistakenly assumed that the bot/group role permissions for the channel would get inherited from the server-level permissions I had set, even though the message at the top of the channel's permission screen explicitly states that the permissions are synced with the category.

The moral of the story? If it *looks* like a permission issue, don't forget to look at *ALL* of the permissions at *every* level.

- Server
- Category
- Channel

Comment: Also make sure your bot is added to the server you want emojis from

Comment: Good point, @stackers. Easy thing to forget. Thank you for bringing that up.