# Discord Bots: Emojis sent by my bot don't get visualized

Tags: discord

It has never been a thing before. Recently I noticed that **some** of emojis sent by one of my bots either in Embeds or as a message don't get visualized (preview in the images below)
[image: Emojis is not visualized in Embed]

[image: Emojis are visualized in Embed]

Then in my other bot, **all** emojis are not visualized (preview in the image below), neither in Embeds nor common messages
[image: Emojis are visualized nowhere]

I am acknowledged that emojis should be sent via a bot in accordance with this format: `<:emoji_name:emoji_id>` and I am sure that the actual emoji name and ID are identical with those sent by the bot.

All my emojis are stored in 3 private servers. There are all my bots (3) that are using emojis. While "Bot 1" sends `:members:` emoji, "Bot 2" is failing to visualize (both of them have identical emoji's name and ID in their codes.

This is really weird and I have no idea what is going on. Maybe it's Discord API. I dunno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would triple check a couple things.
I would make sure that the bot has "Use External Emojis" permissions on both the bot invite (for later use) AND each channel. It maybe the extremely simple answer you over looked just like [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63692883/discord-bot-doesnt-show-emotes-from-other-servers-in-embeds) did. If that fails, then I would look through [this linked StackOverview question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63692883/discord-bot-doesnt-show-emotes-from-other-servers-in-embeds) again to make sure you're covering *all* your bases like he did.